# Searching Records in sql

Tags: sql

I have two tables  products(name varchar2(200)) table which contains 7 000 records and description (fulldescription text) table which contains 10 million records. I want to search each  name from  products table in each and every row of fulldescription field. How to do that?

Comment: Please have a go at it first then post what you tried.

Comment: Hi,  What have you tried?  If you have any code, amend your answer and we can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I will never recommend somthing like this buit still if you want then here you go:-

```
 SELECT fulldescription FROM description
 WHERE fulldescription IN (SELECT name FROM products);
```